# How do I sort my CSV file based on the first column but excluding the first row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I would like to sort the following CSV file by the first column (by name) however I would like it to exclude the first row as that is what my python file uses to determine which column is which.

```
name,age,email
Fin H,14,test@gmail.com
Harvey G,14,test2@gmail.com
name,1,2323
```

It needs to read the file, sort it by the first column (excluding the first row) and then write the sorted version back to the same file.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your difficultly in sorting the file or excluding the first line? Are you using the `csv` module here or trying to iterate over the file line by line?

Comment: @JonClements It is all of it really. Yes I am using the csv module as I am already reading and writing individual lines to it however I need to sort all rows by the first column and I am unable to work out how.

Comment: How are you using the `csv` module... are you using `csv.DictReader` or just `csv.reader`... do you have the rows in a `list` already or...? Do you know how to sort a list or specify a key argument to sort/sorted?

Comment: @JonClements I am using currently csv.DictReader. I have each column in its own array i.e. the first column is in an array called names and looks like ["Fin H", "Harvey G", "Name"]. I don't know how to sort a list.

Comment: Seems like the [Python: Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/sorting.html) will be a worth while read. (Some of the examples it uses are almost exactly what you're trying to do here...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('input', sep = ',')
df = df.sort_values(by = ['name'])
df.to_csv('input', index = False)
```